# Name variable via a loop R

Tags: r, loops, variables, rstudio, cluster-analysis

I'm currently working on a function that will return distance between a point and p clusters.

```
which_cluster<-function(coord){
cluster<-get_cluster(data) # return a matrix
 nbr_clusters=nrow(cluster)
 nbr_dim=ncol(cluster)
 liste<-c()

 for(i in 1:nbr_clusters){
  dist_c_i=0
  for (j in nbr_dim){
   paste('vec_', i, sep = '') 
   dim_j_c_i=cluster[i,j]
   dist_c_i<-dist_c_i+ (dim_j_c_i-coord[i])^2
  }
  dist_c_i<-sqrt(dist_c_i)
  liste<-liste[,dist_c_i]
  }

 return(liste)
 }
```

I want the "i" and "j" in the variable name to be recognize as the i and j of the for loop.

Thank you for your help. Go easy on me, I'm a  beginner ;)

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: And an example of the output you are expecting

Comment: get_cluster(data) returns a matrix that contains the position of clusters' center :         
Dim 1       Dim 2      Dim 3        Dim 4       Dim 5
1 -0.2421963 -0.02219216  1.1548797  6.187503558  4.01138314
2  1.8136751  7.89237995 -0.1976802  1.029745037 -1.66337555
3  0.5433915 -0.20207333 -0.1827094 -0.003705857 -0.02186797
4 -1.0740043  0.17493668  0.3216816 -0.184568336 -0.02079380

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `assign()` after `paste0()`:

```
assign(paste0("dim_", j, "_c_", i), cluster[i,j])
```

Comment: And get(paste0("dim_",j,"\_c\_",i) when on the right side of a <-. But wouldn't it be better to use a two dimensional array 'dim_' instead? Operations on strings and recognizition of associated symbol will be considerably more expensive.

Comment: Thnak you for your comment, The matrix I use is not big. maximum 5 columns et 5 rows, that is why I didnt care using 2 "for loops".

Comment: @K. Youce. I wasn't thinking about memory consumption but about speed. Also your code will be a bit cryptic for other readers. When you need indexing you use vectors and arrays not collections of variables. Did you work with SAS before that?

Comment: No never. I've been learning R for a week now. This code is made to get euclidien distance

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Declaring excessive amounts of variables is slow, and unmanageable.

Instead, use lists and matrixes.

As you seem to try to do a distance matrix, store it as a matrix, indexed by I and j, i.e. `dist[i,j]`.